# Local solution to First order linear PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $U$ be an open convex neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. homeomorphic to a ball.
Let $v\in\Gamma(TU)$ be a non-vanishing vector field on $U$, i.e. $v\neq0$ pointwisely.

**Q** Let $f$ be a smooth function in $U$. Can we find  a smooth function $g$ in a(some) small subset $V\subset U$, such that $vg=f$ holds in $V$?

I donot know if there is an obstruction or a counterexample?

Comment: Related: [Lewy's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewy%27s_example)

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Jose27